# font-size same as element width

Tags: html, css, font-size

Example: [image]http://www.jpeg.cz/images/2016/05/04/uEf8S.jpg

Hello, is it possible to make `font-size` same `width` as element and make it responsive or it must be fixed on every resolution ?

***HTML:***

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor!</h1>
<div id="form-wrapper">
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Jméno a příjmení" />
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
        <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Telefon" />
        <input type="submit" value="ODESLAT" />
    </form>
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    section h1 {
        font-size: xx;
    }
    #form-wrapper {
        width: 320px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    section h1 {
        font-size: xx;
    }
    #form-wrapper {
        max-width: 425px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
    section h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
        font-size: 3.125rem;
    }

    /* form */
    #form-wrapper {
        max-width: 590px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font scaling based on width of container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/T84wL/461/)**

```
h1{ 
     text-transform:uppercase;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:.8px;
       font-size:6.4vw; }
```

Doc Source [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Answer (score 0):

Not relative to the containing element, but you could give a look/try to the viewport relative units `vw`,`vh`,`vmin`,`vmax`.

***Docs***: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths
**Browser support**: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units